# Remove specific observer from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have some observer that contains two arrays

```
source: BehaviorSubject
  observers: (29) [Subscriber, Subscriber, ... FilterSubscriber]
  _value:
  leftTitles: (15) ["a", "b",... ]
  name: "x"
  rightTitles: (14) ["c", "d"...]
```

I do something like that not look great but working

```
const index = this.obs$.source['_value']['leftTitles'].indexOf(tile);
this.obs$.source['_value']['leftTitles'].splice(index, 1);
```

and try something similar using pipe and filter

```
  this.obs$ = this.obs$.pipe(filter(
    res => {
      return res.leftTitles !== tile;
    })
  );
```

It's possible to remove the specific observer from array leftTiles or rightTiles in Observable using operator or other methods?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: As pointed out by @Adam, previous version had a lot of problems. If anyone is interested they can look up the previous version from the *edited* link bellow.

So after looking again at the solution again, I realized what a silly mistake I was doing. I feel embarrassed at the kind of mistake that I did.

Since OP, wants to make changes to the objects inside the `BehaviorSubject`. So now we simply use `map` operator because we need to transform the object rather then `filtering` it. As `filter` implies that you're going to delete some values from a `collection` based on some condition. So the final solution looks like this.

First define a function to filter the array like, this is not required but meh...

```
function arrFilter(tile) { 
    return element => { element != tile; }; 
}
```

and the array filtering part.

```
this.obs$ = this.obs$.pipe(map(res => ({...res, leftTitles: res.leftTitles.filter(arrFilter("1"))})));
```

Comment: Mutation is bad - `filter(res => ({...res,leftTitles:res.leftTitles.filter(arrFilter("b"))}))`. EDIT: Think about the effect of a `distinctUntilChanged()` that might come later in the pipe

Comment: @Adam agreed, I just pointed out how it can be done. But I totally agree by your point.

Comment: @Minato this way clear whole array as result array is empty

Comment: @Minato using Update solution return the same array any idea?

Comment: @Adam when I use your solution I always have original array nothing change?

Comment: @WalterWhite I think it is because `leftTitles` is nested further under `_value`

Comment: @WalterWhite can you try `{...res, _value: {...res._value, leftTitles:res._value.leftTitles.filter(arrFilter("b")})}`

Comment: @Minato when I should wrap in parenthesis spread operator
(filter(res => ({...res, _value: {...res._value.rightTitles:res._value.rightTitles.filter(el => el !== tile)}})));

Comment: @Minato - you SHOULD NOT be accessing it under `_value`, that's a private API, hence the `_`, also hence why you are accessing it via square brackets (because you're not doubt using typescript and typescript tells you `_value` is not a property - do things correctly! What in the world are you trying to do? A BehaviorSubject has a `value` property that you can access.

Comment: @Adam please have a look at the updated answer, apparently we were trying to use `filter` where we should have been using the `map` as we're transforming the `objects` of the `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: @WalterWhite please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Adam using .subscribe() method find index and splice() searched element is ok approach?

Comment: @Minato what better use something like that you created or using subscribe() method find the index searched element and splice it

Comment: @WalterWhite - Personal preference and personal use case - I prefer to do all my "work" in the pipe so whatever comes out at the `subscribe` has already been processed to my needs.